# How to use if condition in SOQL?

Tags: mysql, salesforce, soql

How to reproduce the following statement of MySQL in SOQL:

```
SELECT IF(1 = 2,'true','false');
```

I am trying to do the following:

```
select if(field1=null,false,true) as res from table
```

But it is showing me unknown parsing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible in SOQL.
Not sure of the requirement here but you may use a [formula field](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?language=en&id=customize_functions.htm) instead.